# Why does this recursion work?

Tags: python, function, recursion, integer, logic

I am a bit confused by this recursion:

```
def count(num):
    if num == 0:
        print('Go!',end=' ')
    else:
        count(num-1)
        print(num,end=' ')
count(5)
```

Why does this work? Shouldn't the program stop execution after printing "Go!"?

When I run it in the python visualizer, upon printing "Go!" the execution jumps to the else statement which shouldn't happen...

For example, it prints "Go! 1 2 3 4 5" but I expected it to print "Go!"

Comment: Why *wouldn't* this recursion work?

Comment: Wouldn't the execution jump back to the beginning after the count function is called, never reaching the print statement below it?

Comment: No, that is not how recursion works.

Comment: @ruckarucka it might help you to type the code in [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and visualise it

Comment: @jambrothers thanks, but that was actually what caused my confusion. I couldn't understand why the execution went back to the else statement. I now know that the execution was put on a stack so it still has to return after the recursion is complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Go` is printed *first*, because the other `print()` calls only take place as the recursive calls return. A recursive function call is like any other function call; once the call returns, the next line is executed.

This is what happens:

- `count(5)` is called.

  - `if num == 0` is false, so the `else` branch is taken
  - `count(4)` is called

    - `if num == 0` is false, so the `else` branch is taken
    - `count(3)` is called

      - `if num == 0` is false, so the `else` branch is taken
      - `count(2)` is called

        - `if num == 0` is false, so the `else` branch is taken
        - `count(1)` is called

          - `if num == 0` is false, so the `else` branch is taken
          - `count(0)` is called

            - `if num == 0` is true
            - `print('Go!', end=' ')` is executed

              - write `Go!` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
          - function ends, return
        - `print(num,end=' ')` is executed

          - write `1` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
        - function ends, return
      - `print(num,end=' ')` is executed

        - write `2` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
      - function ends, return
    - `print(num,end=' ')` is executed

      - write `3` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
    - function ends, return
  - `print(num,end=' ')` is executed

    - write `4` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
  - function ends, return
- `print(num,end=' ')` is executed

  - write `5` with trailing space and no newline to stdout
- function ends, return

Each recursive call to the function is a *separate function execution*, other than that the same code is executed each time they are not special. If it helps, mentally *rename* the functions; `count5` calls `count4` and waits for it to return, but `count4` waits for `count3`, etc. Each of those functions is *paused* until the function they called returns. Once `count0` returns, `count1` doesn't just stop, it still has more code to execute!

Comment: I think you misunderstood. My issue isn't that 'Go!' prints first, but why are the other numbers printing at all? Shouldn't the program just print 'Go!' and be done with it?

Comment: @ruckarucka Why do you think it should just print 'Go!' and nothing else? How are you imagining this should work?

Comment: @ruckarucka, when the `num` is greater than 0, it calls the function in `else`. But after returning it has to execute the `print(num,end=' ')` in next line. If after printing `Go!` if you exit the code, then that would be what you want

Comment: @kuro Ah ok that makes sense. I didn't realize that the return statement must execute after the recursion. Thanks.

Comment: @ruckarucka: the recursive call still *returns to the caller*, and that function doesn't just end. It continues with the next line in the function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok thank you that makes sense. I guess where my understanding was flawed was that recursion uses a stack. I overlooked the fact that the instructions are still waiting once the recursion completes.

Answer (score 1):

You pass in 5, so else part is called which triggers `count(4)` which then triggers `count(3)` and so on until count gets 0 and prints `Go`. It is then that the loop starts returning controls and the other numbers are printed.

If you had done `count(0)` then it would have printed just `GO!`

Answer (score 1):

Inside the else block, you're first calling the count(num-1) and then proceeding to print the number.

You're putting it on a stack, so no, you're not done when you print "Go" ... you come back and print numbers.